# negative time varying matrix

Tags: matrices

$P$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.  $Q(t)$ is an $n \times n$ time varying matrix

Does the condition that $P+Q(t)<0$ for all $t$ imply that there exists a constant $k>0$ such that $P+Q(t) < -k I_n$ for all $t$, where $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix

Is that true? If yes, give me a reference please to read about it more. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you comparing two matrices?  What does $A < B$ mean?

Comment: here we are talking about definite positive and definite negative  matrix

Comment: @muzzlator: If it's standard notation, it would be saying that $P + Q(t) + k I_n$ is n.d. (usually, $A < B$ means $A - B$ n.d.).

Comment: fore muzzolator, it's P+Q(t)+kIn which should be negative definite , not P+Q(t)−kIn

Comment: for  gnometorule, you are alright, this is the meaning

Comment: i think it's true because, if P+Q(t) is negative definite matrix then all the eigenvalues are negative, and because In is a positive definite matrix with eigenvalues 1 then,assume that the min eigen value of P+Q(t) is f, we can always find K>0 such that f<-K.

Comment: @user64199, unfortunately only the left hand side is dependent on $t$.  You can just make $Q(t)$ more and more negative definite so no fixed multiple of $I_n$ will match its lowest eigenvalue as $t$ gets big enough.  ie) Let $P = 0$ and $Q(t) = -t I_n$.

Comment: And sorry, I had misread the inequality before.  Unless you can let $k$ be a time varying function, there is no way you can control how negative definite $Q(t)$ gets and so no fixed $k$ will do.

Comment: how about if we assume that Q(t)=a(t)I with a(t) is a continuous decreasing function (example 1/1+t) which is bounded and has its values betwen 0 and 1, is my inequality is acceptibale

Comment: or what about if Q(t)=-a(t) where a(t) is a continuous function has its values between 0 and plus infinity

Comment: Try to solve the question for matrices of size 1x1.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M(t)=P+Q(t)$. You are essentially asking if $M(t)$ is negative definite for all $t$, does it necessarily follow that the eigenvalues of $M(t)$ are bounded away from zero.

The answer is negative. For instance, consider $M(t) = -I/(1+t)$, where $t\ge0$.